# How login my gmail account using vba chrome selenium

Tags: vba, google-maps, selenium-webdriver

I am currently using the code mentioned below to update my data file on Google Maps. However, I'm facing an issue as Google is not allowing auto-login using the code. I would appreciate any suggestions regarding a possible solution.My code and error detail is given below

```
Dim D As WebDriver
Set D = New ChromeDriver
D.Start "Chrome"
D.Get ("https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/home")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
D.FindElementByCss(".RveJvd").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
D.FindElementByCss("#ly0-layerview-import-link").Click
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
```

Error detail

This browser or app may not be secure. Learn more
Try using a different browser. If you’re already using a supported browser, you can try again to sign in.

Comment: OT: I used to use the chrome driver within Excel, however, I find it pretty unreliable and with limited support, if you can, I'd strongly suggest you to go xlwings to call python and use selenium there.

Comment: actually my whole application is using vba and requirement is also vba.

Comment: if anyone have some idea regarding above issue then please inform..thanks